# Can a machine exist making more steps than the current record, which is no busy beaver?

Tags: reference-request, turing-machines

There are some machines in the busy-beaver-competition for turing machines with $5$ states and $2$ symbols for which it is not known whether they halt or not.

> Is it possible that among those machines, there is a halting machine beating the current record with respect to the number of steps, but not being a busy beaver beacuse it doesn't write down more ones than the currect record  ? Or do we know that such a halting machine would also be a new record holder with respect to the number of ones ?

I tend to believe that we cannot rule out this possibility. In fact, I am not sure whether we can even rule out any final output (except trivial ones like an empty tape, if the machine contains $1RH$ forcing at least one $1$ on the tape).

Answer (score 1):

I would say that yes, this is perfectly possible. We know that the champion as far as the number of $1$'s written at the end does not need to be the same as the champion in terms of steps taken (here are [some champions for the quadruple definition Turing machines](http://www.cogsci.rpi.edu/~heuveb/research/BB/champions/B5/champion.html), and the champion for $1$'s is not the same machine as the champion for steps)

So, the situation you describe is can certainly be true at the beginning of our investigations, when *every* machine is a holdout ... so why would that change later on, assuming we still haven't found neither the $1$-champion nor the step-champion?

Answer (score -1):

I don't know the exact machines in the competition, but in general the answer could be "we have a machine which isn't known to halt or diverge, which we've been running for years but has written down fewer 1's so far than the best-known busy-beaver candidate". In that case, exactly one of the following is true, but we don't know which:

- The machine halts, leaving the tape with more $1$'s than the current record holder. Then it is a busy-beaver record beater.
- The machine halts, but does not leave the tape with more $1$'s than the current record holder. Then it is not a busy-beaver.
- The machine diverges. Then it is not a busy-beaver candidate at all, let alone a record-beater.

Comment: Did you consider that a turing machine can delete ones ? The number of ones could decrease, so even a machine halting after a very long time could write fewer ones than the current record holder.

Comment: @Peter Remove the word "exactly" from my answer and it becomes correct; the conclusion is unchanged.

Comment: My question is whether we can rule out the second possibility you mention.